# Averaging Color In ImageJ/Fiji

Tags: java, macros, colors, imagej

Does anyone know how the "average color" function in ImageJ/Fiji works?  How is it averaging the color?  Is there any documentation out there on this function?  I couldn't find any.

Thanks again,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fiji's Menu](http://imagej.net/Fiji's_Menu) wiki page has entries for all available commands.. but it is outdated, and it looks like Average Color was never documented. That is where the documentation should have lived though.

You can take a look at the source file though. To figure out where the Average Color logic was coming from:

- Open the command finder (hotkey: 'L')
- Filter down to "average color"
- We see that Average Color is a part of the VIB plugin

All the Fiji and ImageJ source code is on GitHub.

- https://github.com/fiji/ contains all the Fiji plugins and projects
- ImageJ source is in https://github.com/imagej/imageja

The VIB plugin is part of Fiji, so finally, we get to the [Average Color's run method](https://github.com/fiji/VIB/blob/c98a0ada8cc193aee8c417f4ed58f6970606ca52/src/main/java/Average_Color.java#L53-84).

If looking at the code isn't helpful, I would encourage you to also write to the [ImageJ or Fiji Mailing lists](http://imagej.net/Mailing_Lists).